# How does one prevent a fixed element from scrolling over or under another element?

Tags: html, css

Despite my searches on Google and this site, I haven't been able to find an exact solution to my particular problem.

I have a page with a fixed header and a fixed navigation div which is located in the main content along the right side.  When the page is scrolled to the bottom, the footer scrolls right on top of the nav div.  You can see what i mean here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gAjcr
*(The links list is elongated for dramatic effect to clearly illustrate my issue)*

Is there a way using CSS, or by adding some additional elements, that I can prevent this from happening?  I've tried adjusting margins and padding and what not, to no avail.  The only method that I can think of that might work would be to use some javascript to calculate page offset and footer height, etc, and make the nav div absolutely positioned when it gets towards the bottom, but it seems to be like it might be overkill.

The behaviour I am looking for is when the footer starts to come up the page, it "pushes" the nav div up instead of just laying on top (or underneath) it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `fixed positioning`.

Comment: Well if I didn't, how would my navigation div stay in place as I scroll down the page?

Comment: I know how to do what you have asked but with JQuery

Comment: jQuery is fine, I'm already using it on the page anyway.  I was just hoping there would be a simpler way with CSS and/or HTML.

Comment: Ok then i will post a fiddle in 10 minutes

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo check the fiddle i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdRmA/3/)

**JQuery**

```
var r=$('#hello').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var s=r - $(window).scrollTop();
if(s <= $('#header').height()) {
    $('#header').css({'position':'absolute'});
}
else{
    $('#header').css({'position':'fixed'});
}
});
```

### [Updated fiddle with footer pushing header effect](http://jsfiddle.net/GdRmA/4/)

---

To push the nav above instead of header same JQuery can be used with replacement of the nav id instead of header

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Kya/1/) / Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Kya/1/show/)

Comment: Changing from `fixed` to `absolute` was what I was thinking too if there were no CSS/HTML solutions.  My issue isn't with the header though - that always needs to stay at the top.  What I'm trying to do is to prevent my navigation div from getting overrun by my footer div, as shown in the link I provided.  Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: you mentioned in your question that footer should push the header when it reaches top.Did you check my updated fiddle?

Comment: I said it should push the nav div up, not the header.  I did check your fiddle.  Please look at the link I provided in my post to see my page.  The links in the navigation div are what I want to push up, not the header.  ;)

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo i updated my fiddle .Just minor changes where required in the JQuery. Check the last fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean:

```
 #footer {
    background-color: #0098e9;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -20;
    position:relative; /*add this*/
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I'm trying to make the footer push the navigation div up, like it does the lorem ipsum text.

Comment: Ah hmm I understood wrong then :) Give me a min or so. (just woke up -.-")